# How to open several projects with vim-cocoa?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to have several projects open with the vim-cocoa editor?
I usually open folders work on several files/projects.

Also is there a way to open vim-cocoa from the command line?

Please don't suggest macvim, I know it and it is slow at least lately on my machine or with my projects.

Answer (score 1):

**How to display the content of the working directory in Vim**

```
:Vexp
:Sexp
```

or use [NERD_Tree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658).

**How to do it at launch-time from the command line** (on a Mac)

```
$ open -a vim .
$ open -a vim /path/of/your/folder
```

Comment: Thanks. open -a vim . is good. But if I do it for one folder and again for a different one then the first one is closed and the new one takes over. I work on several projects at the same time. Any tricks I could try to have separate windows?

Comment: I've tried vim-cocoa 10 or so months ago. It's lighter than MacVim but it's also less well integrated. MacVim offers a few otions including the ability to define its behaviour when opening new files from another app. Vim-cocoa doesn't seem to have such an option so I don't think you'll be able to achieve what you want. Try RTGibbons' trick before giving up. Now, `open` has a `-n` flag that is supposed to launch a new instance but here it doesn't work at all as expected and its error messages are quite perplexing. May I suggest you to do your navigation from within Vim itself or use MacVim?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias to `/Applications/Vim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim -g` or you can edit your mvim to something like follows https://gist.github.com/1389839 pay attention to lines 14 and 32

My opinion is to just create an alias in you Shell config.

Note: This doesn't open several projects in separate tabs. If you where to list out several projects it will load them in buffer for you to switch between.

Comment: Assuming you've installed vim-cocoa in /Applications , If not adjust as necessary

Comment: Thanks, didn't quite get it. What do you mean by separate tags? Yeah I see the buffer menu but that is not a good thing for big projects. I use Nerd_Tree. But still need separate windows.

Comment: Vim-cocoa sucks. It doesn't accept more than a few default Mac OS X shortcuts, it doesn't support multiple windows at all. Actually it completely misses the point of using Cocoa: easy integration in the overall system. If you insist on using an almost barebones Vim you should switch to the command line completely.

Comment: @Pod, I meant tabs, Fixed the typo